# WiX installer failed to install on Windows 8 (32 bit Korean)

Tags: wix, installation

Wix installer bundle vcredist.exe and when vcredist.exe try to install on Windows 8 (32 bit Korean) os. "NTVDM CPU is encountered an illegal instruction occuared" error displays. I clean boot system and try to run Wix installer again above error message displayed.

Comment: Which version of vcredist.exe?

Comment: vcredist.exe version 9.0 Reference URL :https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368. When i try to install vcredist.exe standalone it run successfully, But when such vcredist.exe bundle in WiX installer "NTVDM CPU is encountered an illegal instruction occuared" error displays.

Comment: You realize that Windows 8 is not in the list of supported OS versions for that?

Comment: When i tried to install vcredist.exe version 9.0 standalone on Windows 8, it installed successfully.